# JSON Object changes randomly from api

Tags: java, android

I get data from an API in which the JSON object changes randomly, like if it is at `"position": 1`, now it will change randomly to `"number": 1`. So, how can I check in my application if the object is at `"position": 1` or `"number": 1` and use it as `int`?

JSON :-
`{
    "now": [{
        "time": {
            "starts_in": 0,
            "ends_in": 79580,
            "starts_at": 0,
            "ends_at": "2018-01-21T08:00:00.788Z"
        },
        "coins": {
            "free": 8,
            "first_win": 16,
            "max": 52,
            "collected": 0
        },
        "unk1": -88317689,
        "position": 1,
        "xp_multiplier": 0,
        "location_scid": {
            "scid_type": 15,
            "scid_id": 1
        },
        "tid": "TID_WANTED_3",
        "location": "Terre",
        "mode": {
            "name": "Bty",
            "color": "#0884FA",
            "description": " The team wins!"
        },
        "unk4": 0,
        "info": "",
        "unk5": 0,
        "unk6": 0
    }, {
        "time": {
            "starts_in": 0,
            "ends_in": 36380,
            "starts_at": 0,
            "ends_at": "2018-01-20T20:00:00.788Z"
        },
        "coins": {
            "free": 24,
            "first_win": 0,
            "max": 32,
            "collected": 0
        }
    }],
    "later": [{
        "time": {
            "starts_in": 79580,
            "ends_in": 165980,
            "starts_at": "2018-01-21T08:00:00.788Z",
            "ends_at": "2018-01-22T08:00:00.788Z"
        },
        "coins": {
            "free": 8,
            "first_win": 16,
            "max": 52,
            "collected": 0
        },
        "unk1": -88217689,
        "position": 1,
        "xp_multiplier": 0,
        "location_scid": {
            "scid_type": 15,
            "scid_id": 7
        },
        "tid": "TID_GOLDRUSH_1",
        "location": "Mine",
        "mode": {
            "name": "Grab",
            "color": "#AA57CF",
            "description": " An. "
        }
    }]
}`

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: please add your json response.

Comment: I would reconsider if I really want to work with this service.

Comment: You must check both of `position` and `number`, To do this using `Gson`, `Gson` returns `null` if cant to convert JSON to object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
JSONObject c = //Your jsonObject;
  String position = c.getInt("position");
  String number = c.getInt("number");
  if(position!=null){
    //TODO You know it is position and it's int value
  }else if(number!=null){
    //TODO You know it is number and it's int value      
  }else{
    //TODO Its neither of two
  }
```

Comment: Add some comment to your result

Comment: Please refer some tutorials regarding handling JSONData " @user9243753

Comment: I didn't found it anywhere that's why i am asking.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using `Gson` to convert your JSON to a class, you can use both `position` and `number` as attributes for your destination class.

After that, check which one is `null` and which one is not and use that is not null as your number.

Answer (score 0):

Just try this one,

```
JSONObject object = (Your jsonObject);
if(object.has("position")){
      ** do your code here **
}else if(object.has("number"){
      ** do your code here **
}
```